# Issue Exporting array to CSV in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have the following code that queries a MSSQL server database, and then compares the result to a CSV, any rows in the CSV that do not match the counterpart row in the database is added to a new CSV, to create a CSV that only contains changed lines and discards the ones that havent changed.

```
$priceCSV = Import-Csv C:\Users\user\Desktop\pricedelta\Products.csv

$newpriceCSV = @(,@("SKU","BrandName","ID","Name","1stCheapestDistributorName","1stCheapestDistributorPrice","1stCheapestDistributorStock","1stCheapestDistributorProductName","1stCheapestDistributorDeliveryCost","2ndCheapestDistributorName","2ndCheapestDistributorPrice","2ndCheapestDistributorStock","2ndCheapestDistributorProductName","2ndCheapestDistributorDeliveryCost","3rdCheapestDistributorName","3rdCheapestDistributorPrice","3rdCheapestDistributorStock","3rdCheapestDistributorProductName","3rdCheapestDistributorDeliveryCost","4thCheapestDistributorName","4thCheapestDistributorPrice","4thCheapestDistributorStock","4thCheapestDistributorProductName","4thCheapestDistributorDeliveryCost","5thCheapestDistributorName","5thCheapestDistributorPrice","5thCheapestDistributorStock","5thCheapestDistributorProductName","5thCheapestDistributorDeliveryCost","DescriptionType"))

####
#Checks for changed rows are here
####

$NewArray = @()
$names = @("SKU","BrandName","ID","Name","1stCheapestDistributorName","1stCheapestDistributorPrice","1stCheapestDistributorStock","1stCheapestDistributorProductName","1stCheapestDistributorDeliveryCost","2ndCheapestDistributorName","2ndCheapestDistributorPrice","2ndCheapestDistributorStock","2ndCheapestDistributorProductName","2ndCheapestDistributorDeliveryCost","3rdCheapestDistributorName","3rdCheapestDistributorPrice","3rdCheapestDistributorStock","3rdCheapestDistributorProductName","3rdCheapestDistributorDeliveryCost","4thCheapestDistributorName","4thCheapestDistributorPrice","4thCheapestDistributorStock","4thCheapestDistributorProductName","4thCheapestDistributorDeliveryCost","5thCheapestDistributorName","5thCheapestDistributorPrice","5thCheapestDistributorStock","5thCheapestDistributorProductName","5thCheapestDistributorDeliveryCost","DescriptionType")

$skip = 1

foreach($row in $newpriceCSV)
{

    if($skip -eq 1){
        $skip = 0
        continue
    }

    $obj = new-object PSObject
    for ($i=0;$i -lt 30; $i++){
        $obj | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name $names[$i] -value $row[$i]
    }
    $NewArray+=$obj

    $obj=$null
}

$NewArray

$NewArray | Export-Csv -path "C:\Users\user\Desktop\pricedelta\NewProducts.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode
```

The database query and the checks and everything else work fine, however when I try to export the results to a CSV I come up against a few different issues depending on what I try.

If I simply try to Export-Csv $newpriceCSV then I get a bunch of nonsense on the first and second line, then a sequence of commas for every row after, Similar to what is shown here: http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/powershell-from-an-array-to-comma-separated-file-csv-via-the#

After trying the method found on the same link as shown in the code, I get the following error:

```
Unable to index into an object of type System.Management.Automation.PSObject
```

for the row:

```
$obj | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name $names[$i] -value $row[$i]#
```

Really stuck on where to go from here, any help is appreciated

Comment: Apparently the real `$newpriceCSV` doesn't contain arrays, which is what the error message says. Use PowerShell ISE to set a breakpoint inside the loop and evaluate `$row.GetType()` as well as `$row | gm` Also your code is terribly inefficient, switch to using `foreach` as an expression to automatically produce an array and `[PSCustomObject]$hashtable` approach instead of add-member.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're having trouble with the concepts, rather than the techniques.  PS tutorials often treat the concepts as though they are self evident, and sometimes they are.  If you want to understand what's going on, in a simpler case than yours, try replicating the suggested answer provided in the following Q&A and see if you get the same results.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/9d37b573-0f6e-4176-bda5-0e188b41d014/powershell-easy-way-to-output-an-array-to-csv-text-file?forum=ITCG